# Embedded view ( subform ) and form - LOTUS NOTES

Tags: forms, view, lotus-notes

I have a main form called fm_Main. This fm_Main contains an embedded view which has 2 actions: Add & Delete. When I click Add is opening another form called fm_Second and here I can add some fields which will be displayed on the embedded_view on fm_Main.

The problem is: Let say I have 3 documents. All of them contains an empty embedded view. If I add some value fields in one document into the embedded view and then I save that document, all the 3 documents contains that values into the embedded. It should be: just one of them should cotain because I modified only one, the 2 of them shoudn't have that values displayed in the embedded view. Thank you!

PS: Also if I saved one document with an entry into the embedded view. When I want to create another new document, in the embedded view there exists the last entry from the last document. I want to be empty!

Answer (score 0):

You must filter the embedded view to only show the entries related to the currently open main document.
Most programmers would use the UniversalID of the main document, it can be automatically populated into the entries you create.
One thing to think about is that you may want to store the Universal ID in a computed when composed field on teh main document. If you get a replication error in the future, the Universal ID may change, and you will not be able to get to the entries in the embedded view.

I been doing exactly this in several large Notes databases, works perfectly fine.

Comment: Could you give me please an example to use UNID or @Unique function? Thank you

Comment: An example for filtering the embedded view to show only the related entries to the currently open main document. I appreciate

Comment: My embedded view contains 4 columns (fields): numeric1, text, numeric2, numeric3

Comment: I must create another field in the Second form ( smth like text_UNID ) and make the column on the embedded view (which contains the field) categorized? Please help

Comment: Do you already have existing documents that you need to deal with?  Or is this a new application?

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Karl-Henry's suggestion, you should make into a categorized view and use the [Show Single Category](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/Rnext/help6_designer.nsf/855dc7fcfd5fec9a85256b870069c0ab/cf07de2aede754a485256c54004b795e?OpenDocument) feature of the embedded view.  I might suggest using the @Unique function instead of the UNID to relate the Main and Second documents, but that's a matter of preference.  In either case, you have to make sure that the value inherits down into a field in the Second docs, and you can use that field as the category for the view.